# What python framework tactic opensource project based on?

Tags: frameworks, tactic

How are you.
I have just installed tactic project on my local and run it.

https://github.com/Southpaw-TACTIC/TACTIC

I would like to know what python framework this project based on.
There was doc for developer api, but it doesn't explain about structure of itself.
Where can I find more detailed doc for structure of source project?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, they do not provide any documentation on the detailed structure or the framework on which it is developed. If you can share the use case, probably I can try to help with a more relevant answer

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I just noticed it.  TACTIC is written in Python on the server side and uses CherryPy to serve out widgets to the browser.  It doesn't use on any other of the Python frameworks (ie: Django) as it is a framework unto itself.  Having said that, TACTIC can also be used as a library so that it can exist "headless" and interface with other frameworks.